# Count distinct in R groupby, first spliting the cells by ","?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have data in format given below

| a | b |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A,B |
| 1 | A |
| 1 | B |
| 2 | A,B |
| 2 | D,C |
| 2 | A |
| 2 | A |

What I need is when groupby column 'a' need the distinct values of column 'b'

| a | count |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 4 |

Because for 1 we only have 2 distinct values, i.e. A,B
but for 2 we have 4 ,i.e. A,B,C,D.

I can first explode the data in tall format and then do the groupby, but since I have few other aggregation to be done so I was thinking of way to do in one line.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please provide your input data as code that recreates the data.frame in R. You could use the dput() function or similar.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `aggregate` in base R :

```
aggregate(b~a,df, function(x) length(unique(unlist(strsplit(x, ',')))))

#  a b
#1 1 2
#2 2 4
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(a = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), b = c("A,B", 
"A", "B", "A,B", "D,C", "A", "A")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

Comment: Thanks, I used this in dplyr and it worked

Answer (score 0):

Using `tidyr::separate_rows` and `dplyr::n_distinct` this could be achieved like so:

```r
library(dplyr)

d %>% 
  tidyr::separate_rows(b) %>% 
  group_by(a) %>% 
  summarise(count = n_distinct(b))
#> `summarise()` ungrouping output (override with `.groups` argument)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 2
#>       a count
#>   <int> <int>
#> 1     1     2
#> 2     2     4
```

**DATA**

```r
d <- read.table(text = "a   b
1   A,B
1   A
1   B
2   A,B
2   D,C
2   A
2   A", header = TRUE)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. I tried this but like I mentioned I have few other columns which I need to aggregate and using separate_rows() function duplicate those rows. Can you please help with that?

Comment: Hm. As it depends on the structure of your data I can only guess. If each of your columns contains the same number of elements per row then you could do `tidyr::separate_rows(b, c, d, ...)`. Otherwise I would suggest to update your question and example data.

Answer (score 0):

Base R using `Map()`:

```
setNames(do.call(c, Map(function(x){length(unique(trimws(unlist(strsplit(x, ",")))))}, 
    with(df, split(b, a)))), names(df))
```